# ruby whenever gem: scoping :mailto to specific tasks

Tags: ruby, cron, whenever

Is it possible to scope `:mailto` to specific tasks in `schedule.rb`? I'm thinking something like the following:

```
# pseudo-code
env MAILTO=address_1@mail.com
#task_1

env MAILTO=address_2@mail.com
#task_2

#etc
```

The only reference I can find in the source code is in the following test case:

`should "output MAILTO environment variable" do
    assert_match "MAILTO=someone@example.com", @output
  end`

Answer (score 0):

Per [this question on server overflow](https://serverfault.com/questions/133058/how-to-send-the-output-from-a-cronjob-to-multiple-e-mail-addresses) as well as research into `cron` it appears that most cron daemon packages would not support having task-relative email addresses.